# Failed to detect Cypress running from React app

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I want to check in my React app if it is running under Cypress, so looking at the documentation the suggestion is this:

https://docs.cypress.io/faq/questions/using-cypress-faq#Is-there-any-way-to-detect-if-my-app-is-running-under-Cypress

Basically we should check for the environment variable `process.env.CYPRESS` but that is returning `undefined` for me.

1 - Does anyone know what could possibly cause this?

My Cypress version is **7** and my React version is **17**, if that helps in any way.

2 - Another suggestion from the documentation is to check for `window.Cypress` but I am using Typescript, does anyone know how to set/get that type?

Comment: Not sure about `process.env.Cypress` , but `window.Cypress` will definitely work. At runtime Typescript is behind you, but if you get type errors in the editor or even compiler just type as `any`.

Comment: @Fody I am still getting it as `undefined`

Comment: Where are you checking it?

Comment: inside a useEffect of a customised react hook. 
another thing is that that code is inside an iFrame which is inside another iFrame, I am suspecting this is the problem